# Android - String em Base64 decode para pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, base64

Olá,

O objectivo é fazer o decode de uma string em Base64 e passar para formato PDF e abrir (**não é preciso fazer o download para o dispositivo android**).

Neste momento tenho isto:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Sapo" + position + base64Strisng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Test", base64String.toString());
        try {


            //Não sei como fazer o decode da string e passar para o itent

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Sapo" + position + base64Strisng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Test", base64String.toString());

        byte[] pdfStream = Base64.decode(base64String, 0);
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfStream);
        File file ;
        try {

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "sapo.pdf");
            Logger.getLogger("createFile: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Update 3**

Problema resolvido, estava a fazer de forma errada o decode

O que tinha (errado):

> byte[] pdfStream = base64String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

O que alterei (correcto)

> byte[] pdfStream = Base64.decode(base64String, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu objetivo é usar o arquivo somente como temporário, você pode usar a função **createTempFile**, como mostra no exemplo abaixo:

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
File file;
try {
    String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
    file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error while creating file
}
    return file;
}
```

No site do [android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) tem mais exemplos

Comment: Actualizei o meu post, pois fiz alterações.